# How to read specific transaction status from payubizz payment response array

Tags: arrays

Please see the following link for the response array
https://www.swapnilpatni.com/Verify_payment.php

Comment: see this answer. and make it as json. and you can get it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41980846/android-parsing-using-php-genrated-json/41981758#41981758

Comment: thank you for giving a solution,but it does not work...

Comment: see. what you want to do. how to read specific data means, in which language you have read that transaction status. your question is clear and unclear.

Comment: thank u for response.. i want  read the specific element of that array..

Comment: I tried ...$bt[]=$o['transaction_details']['58e33e1c29d01']['status'];
print_r($bt);   but i cant get that element.. Please help me..

Comment: i used core php for this...

Comment: post your php code.

Comment: Please see a link: https://www.swapnilpatni.com/Verify_payment.php

Comment: I updated my link with my code and my output..Please help me...

Comment: there is no code in the link. it display's only array output. first double check your side about your code then post here.

Comment: please see respected link: I updated the code on that page.Just open page refresh that page to see the latest changes..

Comment: Latest webpage link:  https://www.swapnilpatni.com/Verify_payment.php

Comment: Ok wait. i will see it

Comment: I think we are thinking in which way of that array response response we got that is not in expected format..due to this we are not able to get that specific element...

Comment: $o=transaction array;

Comment: $arrayval = json_decode($o,TRUE);

Comment: $trnarray=$arrayval['transaction_details'];

Comment: the problem is solved. I can read the each and every transaction status using $trnarray;

Comment: using foreach loop of $trnarray;       My problem is solved...